# LibreOffice Macro does not recognize JRE

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, jre

I'm brand new to using macros and spreadsheets and am having trouble with LibreOffice Calc recognizing the JRE that I have installed. I've spent a day following advice on this topic on other forums, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm applying to a coding bootcamp and need to complete a task using an Excel spreadsheet, but can't start the fun coding part until I get this installation problem figured out. I currently have java version "1.8.0_101" and Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13).

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I am having trouble with LibreOffice Calc recognizing the JRE that I have installed

1. Close LibreOffice Calc.
2. Run LibreOffice.
3. Menu "Tools" > "Options".

   > [image]
4. Click "Advanced".

   > [image]
5. Enable "Use a Java Runtime environment".
6. Click "Add".
7. Select the installation directory of your JRE and click "OK".

   > [image]
8. Check the Radio button to the left of the newly configured JRE (if necessary).

   > [image]
9. Click "OK".
10. Close LibreOffice.
11. Start LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: Thank you! I think it's finally working! Now to figure out how to use macros!!